# Using jquery to get an alt attribute with a link

Tags: jquery

One jquery plugin that I know supports links in the captions is the NIVO slider. Basically what I have is a jquery plugin that uses the alt attribute of an image to display it as a caption. I was wondering how difficult it would be to reference a DIV in the alt attribute and have it display the DIV.

Here's the jquery:

```
$('.thumb_container').click(function(){

      var handler = $(this).find('.large_image');
      var newsrc  = handler.attr('src');
      var newcaption  = handler.attr("alt");
      loadPhoto(newsrc, newcaption);

 });
```

So what I want is the alt attribute of an image to reference a DIV (i.e. alt="#example") and in the DIV will be a link that will be shown as the caption. Is there any easy way to do this? What I have above works, but the caption displays #example not what is in the #example DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('.thumb_container').click(function(){
    var handler = $(this).find('.large_image');
    var newsrc  = handler.attr('src');
    var newcaption  = $(handler.attr("alt")).html();
    loadPhoto(newsrc, newcaption);
});
```

focus on the jquery selector around handler.attr("alt")

Comment: No, that's not right. `$()` creates a jQuery object, it isn't important (or usable) to display text.

Comment: So you want the text of the div or the div itself?

Comment: The contents of the div. So the text of the div because I have a link in the div.

Comment: If you want the text of the div then you can put .html() or .text() at the end depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Sorry I dont fully understand where you want that tag.

Comment: I lied, I figured it out. Thank you very much.